# Login timeouts: in what cases are do you use them?

Tags: authentication, session-timeout

I'm wondering when login timeouts are being used, specifically when using same session (same browser session). On a number of sites I have completed recently I have added 60 minute timeouts and they seem to be causing problems, such as users are not able to fill out larger forms (like a resume submission--people don't think of copying their resume from another program or saving part way through). On one site, I have implemented a div/popup forcing the user to enter their password to continue in the current session, without having to login again.

But on other sites, such as Facebook, it seems you are never logged out as long as you are using the same browser window, even without "remembering" your password.

The main reason I usually use timeouts is to ensure the data is secure, such that another party can't sit down at the computer a few hours later and use the system as the original user.

I'm wondering how you decide when a site should time out users because of inactivity?

I'm thinking the answer would be language agnostic.

Answer (score 1):

IMO, they're valid when:

1. security is critical (ie. banking)
2. the likelihood of seat-swapping is
   high (ie. public terminals)

Regardless, there may be instances like your resume system, where you want people on public terminals to be able to carry out an act that may leave them inactive for longer than your desired or necessary timeout.

I suppose you just have to handle that in a smart fashion - either figure out a way they can get the data in quicker (which would be ace, spending an hour filling out a form is not fun - can they just upload a file?), or ensuring they can continue without any data loss after being prompted to log in again.

Answer (score 0):

Even though 60 minutes seems like a long time to fill out a single form (perhaps the forms should be divided into multiple pages?), you can probably use SlidingExpiration to solve the problem where your users get logged out even though the browser session is alive.

I think the timeout for an auth cookie is a Security level decision. If your site is SSL secured, you would probably have minimal timeout values (user session would expire within a matter of minutes). On the other hand, for sites with non-critical security, you could set a medium timeout value.

Answer (score 0):

When I sign on to online banking, for example, it asks me whether or not I am using a "public terminal": and if I say yes then it enforces stricter security, or if no then laxer.